# Entity Framework loading all data but in child column sort order

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 and entity framework Database first(EF5).
I Have two tables 'Items' is master table and 'ItemDetails' is slave. I want to fetch and show data of both tables in single view but order all the data by column 'Number' which is column from slave table 'ItemDetails' .
I am getting data but not able to sort it by 'Number'
Please suggest any query for this case.

Comment: Do you have any code examples of what you've done.  Do you know how to use Include statement in LINQ?

Answer (score 1):

Is the relationship between `Item` and `ItemDetails` a one-to-one? If so, you can simply do:

```
db.Items.OrderBy(o => o.ItemDetails.Number);
```

If not, you'll need to use an aggregate like `Min` or `Max` as you can't order by a list of things:

```
db.Items.OrderBy(o => o.ItemDetails.Min(m => m.Number))
```

Or

```
db.Items.OrderByDescending(o => o.ItemDetails.Max(m => m.Number))
```

Depending on the directionality you want.

Answer (score 0):

Look at an example of how you can make an `OrderBy`:

```
var Query = from category in categories
            join product in products on category.ID equals product.CategoryID 
            orderby product.CategoryID
            select new { Category = product.CategoryID, ProductName = product.Name };
```

I also leave [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) for an example.